# Creating a list-backed SQL Server database without using External Content Types

Tags: sql-server, external-content-type, database-connection

I'm trying to develop a list backed by a SQL Server database running on AWS in Sharepoint 2010 (also running on AWS), but I'm running into issues regarding authentication to the database.  The only way I've found out how to create a list backed by a database is to use External Content Types, but when connecting to a data source, I have to use one of the three authentication methods:

1. Windows credentials
2. Impersonated Windows credentials
3. Pass through credentials

#1 is not supported on AWS for RDS, and #2 and #3 require access to the Central Admin tool in order to create a Secure Application Store ID, which I do not have because it's managed by the corporate IT team (assume right now that I won't be able to have them add a key, although I'm still investigating this possibility).

I can create a database connection by adding a new data source, but this doesn't show up when I browse for data sources when creating an External Content Type.  This DB connection allows me to use standard SQL Server authentication by specifying the username + password.  Is there any way I can use this DB connection to create a DB backed list?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to connect through WCF Service:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556831(v=office.14).

WCF on AWS:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=323145